# Integration of GORM queries

Tags: sql, go-gorm

This is my GORM model

```
type Movie struct {
    ID          uint       `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Title       string     `gorm:"size:255;not null"`
    ReleaseDate time.Time
    RunTime     int
    MPAARating  string
    Description string     `gorm:"size:1000"`
    Image       string
    CreatedAt   time.Time
    UpdatedAt   time.Time
    Genres      []Genre    `gorm:"many2many:movie_genres;" json:"genres"`
    GenresArray []int
}

type Genre struct { 
    ID        uint       `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Genre     string
    Checked   bool
    Movies    []Movie    `gorm:"many2many:movie_genres;" json:"movies"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
}
```

I'd like to update movie genres by new genre ids.
This is my first try.
First it get all movie genres for the given movie ID. It then creates a map of genre IDs to movie genres. This map is used to check if a genre ID is already in the database. Finally, the query removes any movie genres that are not in the list of genre IDs, and adds any movie genres that are in the list of genre IDs but not in the database.

```
func UpdateMovieGenres(movieID int, genreIDs []int) error {
    // Get all movie genres for the given movie ID.
    movieGenres := []MovieGenre{}
    err := db.Where("movie_id = ?", movieID).Find(&movieGenres).Error
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Remove any movie genres that are not in the list of genre IDs.
    for _, movieGenre := range movieGenres {
        if !contains(genreIDs, movieGenre.GenreID) {
            err := db.Delete(&movieGenre).Error
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
    }

    // Add any movie genres that are in the list of genre IDs but not in the database.
    for _, genreID := range genreIDs {
        if !contains(movieGenres, genreID) {
            movieGenre := MovieGenre{
                MovieID: movieID,
                GenreID: genreID,
            }
            err := db.Create(&movieGenre).Error
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func contains(slice []int, val int) bool {
    for _, v := range slice {
        if v == val {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

My Problem: It query to database many times for simple purpose.
I want to integrate all queries to a nested one to improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

why not use Where().Delete(). one time delete all

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).